# Twitter's Bootstrap popover with selector and data-* attributes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selector, popover, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using

```
$(document).popover({
    selector: '.selector'
});
```

ignores any `data-*` attributes specified in target elements.
For example

```
<a class="selector" title="bla" data-content="some html" data-html="true">link</a>
```

popover will skip `data-html` attribute.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/YsEqb/

The question is: How make bootstrap take into account `data-*` attributes in case of delegated attachment ({ selector: '.selector' }) ?

**UPD**
This was [confirmed as bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9222) and [fixed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/1abb7947c2b24041efe02ae8e243e62e6afeb2c8). Version 3.0.0 won't have this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data-elements are not used caused they are set on initialization instead of on show of the element. This won't work for a selector which only use the same options for all set in your initializator. I don't know this is a bug. (**update** yes it is and it is fixed: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9222)

Quick fix extend your show function and set the options (again) there:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>    

var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
  var $e = this.$element
  if (typeof($e.attr('data-html')) != 'undefined')this.options.html = ($e.attr('data-html')==='true') 
  if (typeof($e.attr('data-placement')) != 'undefined')this.options.placement = $e.attr('data-placement');
  /* add other options here */
  tmp.call(this);
}
```

This will work for Twitter's Bootstrap 2.x and Twitter's Bootstrap 3(RC1)

Also see: http://jsfiddle.net/bassjobsen/YsEqb/1/

Note when using the CDN as above you will got a JS error on closing the popover (TypeError: this.remove is not a function) see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8887

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the selector you are resetting the data-html value back to the default of false

so explicitly stating:

```
$(document).popover({
    selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]',
    html:true
});
```

will  set the data-html value to true in this case. 
[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GCrem/QTCZC/)

Comment: I need exactly what was asked: I need to toggle options **with attributes**

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using

```
 $(document).popover({
    selector: '.selector'
});
```

If you want using selector then this is the code:

```
$('body').popover({
        selector: '.selector'
    });
```

or

```
$('.selector').popover();
```

Comment: (1) Wrong answer (check http://jsfiddle.net/SBcyd/) (2) Answer to the wrong question