# how to use value of a data element as a selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to use a data element's value as a selector.
I want to use the "#login" in the data-select attr to select the span in the ff code:

```
<div class="pop" data-select="#login" data-toggle="popover" title="What is it?" data-content="Amazing content."  data-placement="left">Help!</div>
<span id="login">okay</span>
```

I have tried this (using bootstrap js):

```
<script>
  $('.pop').popover({selector: '[data-popover]'});
</script>
```

Thank you...

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is unclear.

Comment: Actually it isn't, lemme explain what I meant. Bootstrap popovers claim to support popovers that can be triggered by a button (for example) but show elsewhere, say an input element far from the triggering button. But there is a big bug that does not let the function's selector option work.

Comment: I've successfully used a workaround in my answer post below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created a working workaround!!!
I figured that a button could be used to trigger the popover on the element that you actually want the popover to appear on.
Let me show you what I mean:

JS >>
`<script>
     $('.pop').popover({delay: { show: 200, hide: 100 }});
     var cont = $(".pop-sel")[0].dataset.select;
     $('body').on('click', '.pop-sel', function(e) {
         $(cont).popover('toggle');
     });
     $(cont).popover({trigger: 'manual', delay: { show: 200, hide: 100 }});
</script>`

HTML >>
    `<span class="badge pop-sel" id="loginSel" data-toggle="popover" data-select="#login">?</span>`
    `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" maxlength="10" value="" data-title="What is xIdentity?" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?"  data-placement="right" data-selector="loginSel" required>`

This therefore makes the badge to trigger the input's popover.
Thanks to `guest271314` response, it gave me the idea!
If you created a fiddle, pls comment it's location for others.
If I have spare time I might add a fiddle.
You guys are great!

Answer (score 1):

```
$($(".pop")[0].dataset.select)
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/aGTKW/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'}`

Comment: I actually want the popover to toggle on another element without using js everytime to call each popover. I am trying to use data- to pass in the data-selector `$('.pop').popover({selector: '???'});` ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but I think this might help you.

```
dataSelect = $this.data('select');
```

This will get the content of the data-tag for you, then you can use the content in the "dataSelect" variable to select the span.

If this isn't what you're looking for, maybe you could setup a JS fiddle or be more specific with your question.

Comment: I actually used: `var selector = ('.pop').attr('data-selector'); $('.pop').popover({selector: selector});` and `var selector = ('.pop').attr('data-selector'); $('.pop').popover({selector: '+selector+'});` even using `console.log()` to test what was returned by `var selector`. But even noticed that using: `$('.pop').popover({selector: '#inputEmail'});` does not solve the issue.

Comment: I actually noticed that: `$('.pop').popover({selector: '#inputEmail'});` seems to crash the popover (silently) as it would create the popover without it on the element that's creating the popover (ie: `$('.pop')`. I'm still working towards a solution, help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**[Refer this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011929/twitters-bootstrap-popover-with-selector-and-data-attributes)**

> Always search in SO before asking question ;)

@Bass Jobsen has given an excellent solution for that:

The data-elements are not used caused they are set on initialization instead of on show of the element. This won't work for a selector which only use the same options for all set in your initializator.

Quick fix extend your show function and set the options (again) there:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>    

var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
  var $e = this.$element
  if (typeof($e.attr('data-html')) != 'undefined')this.options.html = ($e.attr('data-html')==='true') 
  if (typeof($e.attr('data-placement')) != 'undefined')this.options.placement = $e.attr('data-placement');
  /* add other options here */
  tmp.call(this);
}
```

Comment: When I saw this, I felt it was finally over. I just researched and found out that the popover plugin in bootstrap is very buggy. Sadly your reply does not solve it as it does not display the popover anywhere.

Comment: I'm actually surprised some fiddles have something to work with.